# sizeof for vector<bool> and for other vectors

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector

I see on VS2015 compiler that `sizeof(std::vector<bool>)` is 16 bytes, but for other types, e.g. `for vector<int>`, sizeof is only 12 bytes (first and last pointers + capacity, 4 bytes for each). I have seen implementation for `vector<bool>`, it contains an underlying `vector<unsigned int>` (12 bytes) and its own size (4 bytes). But underlying vector also contains its size, which is not needed because can be easily computed from size of inner `vector<bool>`. I can't find any reasons for that redundancy. Is this an imperfection of `vector<bool>` implementation in Visual Studio and can it be implemented without excess member for size?

Comment: The C++ standard does not require any particular `sizeof` of any particular template class instance. Whatever the actual size of the underlying instantiated class, this is immaterial, and nobody really cares about the actual reason why a given template class instance's size is what it is.

Comment: `sizeof()` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Oh? How exactly do you propose to calculate the vector's size from the inner vector's size? You say it can be easily done, but as far as I can see it cannot be done at all.

Comment: Can one avoid the overhead? Sure. Would saving 4 bytes in a resource handler like `std::vector` be worth the dev time (and the potentially slower `std::vector<bool>::size`)? Most likely no.

Comment: `std::bitset` comes to mind to solve that puzzle.

Comment: @hvd He probably got outer and inner mixed up. Anyways, the answer remains: "Who cares?"

Comment: @hvd I mean that it can be implemented without inner vector and only with one member for size instead of two

Comment: This is nitpicking completely irrelevant details. There are *very few* situations where this will actually matter. Don't waste your time on pointless details like this.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Why?

Comment: @user3514538 Ah, yeah, that would be possible, but that means code duplication, that means the code that's already there for `vector<unsigned int>` (and other types) to manage the memory cannot easily be re-used. (Admittedly there's not all that much in there.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say you're storing 48 `bool`s on a platform where `unsigned int` is 32-bit.

There is no way for the innermost vector to contain 1½ elements, so it has to contain two elements and then the encapsulating class remembers that the "first" 48 bits across the two `unsigned int`s are meaningful, and the final 16 are currently meaningless.

Dinkumware could have chosen to use something other than `vector<unsigned int>` for the innermost container in order to avoid the redundancy, but apparently they quite rightly decided that this would be a complete waste of time for next to no gain.